# The autoplay window has stopped showing when connecting my digital camera

Tags: windows-7, camera

Recently, when I connect my digital camera, the camera screen shows that it is connected to the computer, but nothing else happens. I have been downloading pictures previously with no problem.

How can I re-enable autoplay?

Comment: Can you please provide us with OS information? What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You might have turned off AutoPlay by mistake for the camera.

1. Connect the camera, then go to Control Panel and click on **AutoPlay** (if you don't find it use the search box).
2. Scroll down till you see your camera listed under the **Devices** section.
3. Select **Ask me every time** or other default action from the corresponding drop-down box:

   [image: 1]
4. Click **Save**, disconnect the camera, reconnect and see if the AutoPlay dialog pops up.

For more help check out the [AutoPlay FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/autoplay-frequently-asked-questions).